# Relationship Advice/Advice Column Corpora?

Tags: english

I have the benefit of having a fairly green field project on my hands where I need to perform some language analysis on advice and etiquette giving. This involves both centralized sources (advice columns in newspapers) as well as decentralized ones (online advice forums, like subreddits or ask metafilter). Does anyone know of any (English language) sources that already compile this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "advice and etiquette giving": Could you give some examples, so that we have a better idea how to help you? Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious about newspaper columnists like Carolyn Hax (http://www.washingtonpost.com/pb/carolyn-hax), Ask Amy, Dear Prudence, and stuff like that. I was fishing for a possibly easy solution for aggregating these resources other than scraping them. Anyway if you have to ask, it probably doesn't exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

English Language&Usage has some material that might interest you, under some of its tags like this one:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness

The data is licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required.